# Permutation test error for likelihood ratio test of mixed model in R: permlmer, lmer, lme4, predictmeans

Tags: r, permutation, lme4, mixed-models

I would like to test the main effect of a categorical variable using a permutation test on a likelihood ratio test. I have a continuous outcome and a dichotomous grouping predictor and a categorical time predictor (Day, 5 levels).

Data is temporarily available in rda format via [this Drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A9xSdsBsMMgt-iRgxFOYnw95gNcvK7iL).

```
library(lme4)
lmer1 <- lmer(outcome ~ Group*Day + (1 | ID), data = data, REML = F, na.action=na.exclude)
lmer2 <- lmer(outcome ~ Group + (1 | ID), data = data, REML = F, na.action=na.exclude)

library(predictmeans)
permlmer(lmer2,lmer1)
```

However, this code gives me the following error:

*Error in density.default(c(lrtest1, lrtest), kernel = "epanechnikov") : 
  need at least 2 points to select a bandwidth automatically*

The following code does work, but does not exactly give me the outcome of a permutated LR-test I believe:

```
library(nlme)
lme1 <- lme(outcome ~ Genotype*Day,
                  random = ~1 | ID,
                  data = data,
                  na.action = na.exclude)

library(pgirmess)
PermTest(lme1)
```

**Can anyone point out why I get the "epanechnikov" error when using the `permlmer` function?**

Thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Sounds like you don't have enough data to do the test.

Comment: @MrFlick I've added the data.

Comment: The only thing in that data.rda file is a length-1 vector containing the word "data". So I think the error may be a bit misleading but it is informative in the sense that it's telling you you don't really have any _data_. Voting to close as essentially a "typo".

Comment: @42 That is probably just an issue with the link. I'm pretty sure I have data and the file that is linked is the correct file... I think I would be able to diagnose a data.frame is non existent when running a code like above :)

Comment: Did you try downloading the file and then using `load` in an R session?

Comment: @42 Yes, I did exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with NANs, remove all nans from your dataset and rerun the models. I had the same problem and that solved it.

Comment: Ah thank you, I was wondering about that. I thought that the `na.action = na.exclude` element in the `lmer` function should have taken care of that.

Comment: Yes, me too! It's probably a bug, rather than a feature :-)

Comment: OK, I've actually tried it now and it solves it indeed!